# Tripple OS, WIN, UBUNTU, KALI

Tags: dual-boot, windows, kali

I'm unable to access Windows after installing KALI and Ubuntu on my PC.
The only alternatives I get when turning on computer is to either enter Kali or Ubuntu. 
So I tried to update grub `sudo update-grub` with no solution.

Also the Windows ISO is on partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3` after opening *Disks* in Ubuntu.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: I did take a look on that one, but doesn't solve my problem. When I turn on my pc, I get KALI-logo with choosing either to run on UBUNTU or KALI..

Comment: That question is like a shopping mall, there are a lot of answers and you need to browse around. The top upvoted answers are usually better.

Comment: Well, when I do run the command as explained on the question, I do get this: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

Comment: That error is what you get when you try to run a graphical application as root. To make that error go away use a non-graphical text editor like nano text editor or simply use `sudoedit /path/to/file`.

Comment: Okay, Did that now. And «Windows UEFI» apears on boot screen. I select it, then I get «invalid signature». Is this known problem?

Comment: secure boot violation invalid signature detected check secure boot ...

Answer (score 0):

It's better to install multiple operating systems in order that is supported by the native installers.

So, my recommendation for all those starting out would be to keep it simple, install windows first (if it is not already installed), then install Ubuntu.

Next, download Virtualbox and install a Kali VM. Kali as a VM will be a lot better of many reasons and let you use the tool as intended. The other great way to use Kali is via a live USB.

The reason for this is that when you are doing pentests you want to be able to remove client data from your systems *completely* to ensure it is not exposed inadvertently in any context outside of the report.